# function repetition on button click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make an ajax function run by clicking a button (modal). The strange thing is, if I click the button the function runs perfectly.
But if I click the button again the function runs twice, if I click it one more time the function runs 3 times and so on.

Here is the code:

```
$('#delClient').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#delClntMod').modal('hide');
    doDelete(json);
});
```

Here is the doDelete() function:

```
function doDelete(json) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/clients/delClient',
        data: json,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 7000,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.xstatus == 'success') {
                var options = {};
                $('#client-' + data.clientId).effect('highlight', options, 2500, callback);
            }
            $(this).queue(function () {

                $('#message-title').html(data.messageTitle);
                $('#message-body').html(data.message);
                $("#message").addClass("alert-" + data.xstatus);
            }).queue(function () {
                $('#message').removeClass('hidden');
            });
            $(this).dequeue();

            // run the effect
            $("#message").delay(6000).slideUp('slow', function () {
                $('#message').css('display', '');
                $('#message').addClass('hidden');
                $("#message").removeClass("alert-" + data.xstatus);
                $('#message-title').html('');
                $('#message-body').html('');
            });

            function callback() {
                $('#client-' + data.clientId).fadeOut(500, function () {
                    $('#client-' + data.clientId).remove();
                });
            };
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {},
        complete: function (XMLHttpRequest, status) {}
    });
}
```

Here is the console log after clicking the button 3 times:

```
POST http://aum-crm.dev/users/userDelete 200 OK 170ms   
POST http://aum-crm.dev/users/userDelete 200 OK 628ms   
POST http://aum-crm.dev/users/userDelete 200 OK 214ms
```

The is after clicking the button 3rd time and clearing the console. So just from one click I got this result.

The HTML Code for the modal is:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="delClntMod" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delUsrModLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo t('delClient'); ?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <strong><?php echo t('rusure', 'client'); ?></strong>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="delClient" type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><?php echo t('delete'); ?></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><?php echo t('cancel');?></button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I don't know if that could help, I am having the first click to call the modal and the second click to fun the doDelete function:

```
$(".delclnt").click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.get('/main/checkSession', function(data) {
        if( data == "Expired" ) {
            window.location.replace("main");
        }
    });

    var url = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    action = url[0];
    clientId = url[1];

    var json = {};

    json.action = action;
    json.clientId = clientId;

    $('#delClient').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#delClntMod').modal('hide');
        doDelete(json);
    });
});
```

Comment: this looks like the code `$('#delClient').click(function(event){..});` is executed 3 times... add a `console.log()` before the `.click()` call and see how many times it is getting called

Comment: Where is the `click` handler being bound? You've shared the handler code, but it seems as if that's getting rebound on every click.

Comment: You're somwhow attaching the event handler on every click, so each time you click, a new event handler is attached, making the function run twice once clicked once, three times once clicked two times etc. It's not apparent exactly where this is happening from the posted code !

Comment: I did add a console.log() and it's showing that every time I click it it is running the function 3 times then next time 4 times then 5 times and so on.